# Is it okay to make a network request for every item in a list?

Tags: android, listview, mobile, request

It's a common pattern in mobile to request a page of data, then display that paged data as a list, then subsequently request an image URL for each item. So if there's 8 items on the screen, we can make 8 concurrent image requests. This seems to be okay based on how prevalent it is.

What's a lot less common is to make subsequent requests to display other types of data. Using the example above, if we also had to make an HTTP request to fetch a description field, then we'd have to make 16 requests total (for the image and description).

My questions:

1. In terms of latency/resource usage, is there a difference between the image request and a typical GET? The former is usually obfuscated by a library like Picasso.
2. Aside from adding complexity to both code and UI/UX, are there any other drawbacks to making subsequent data requests for each item in a list?

Comment: `Is it okay to make a network request for every item in a list?` You are already doing that as you request an image for every item. You mean: `Is it okay to make several network requests for every item in a list?`

Comment: `is there a difference between the image request and a typical GET? ` Images are mostly requested wit a GET. So i see no difference.

Comment: `if we also had to make an HTTP request to fetch a description field` . Interesting. I'm about to do that too and i see no problem. You could of course get an image and a description with one GET but you cannot use an image library then. Please program it today and tell... i'm interested in your findings.

Comment: I assume you only request images at the time they scroll in place.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in latency between an image request and a GET because an image request is a GET.  It's a GET on the image file's URL.

Drawbacks-  lag.  If you get the entire list of data in 1 request, you can display it all immediately.  If you get 1 request per item, you have to wait to display items 2...n.  Sometime you'll notice that a page in the app will load the images a split second after the text, this is because they're still downloading the image.  Its an ok effect with images, especially if you know and can reserve the size.  Its more noticable and disruptive with large elements, especially if it forces other elements to move down the page.  Also remember that web requests may not come back in the order they're sent, which can cause odd effects with list elements filling in out of order.

Then there's server and db usage-  its less load on both to do one request and return 10 items than to do 10 requests each for 1 item.  Obviously there's an inflection point in there somewhere, where if you return 1000 items and the app only uses 10 you wasted the time to get the other 990.  So its impossible to give 100% accurate advice without knowing a lot more details about typical usage patterns, how much it takes to generate these results, etc.